# something wrong with my OnElementChanged in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create the route lines in my android project map in xamarin forms, and here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using neoFly_Montana;
using neoFly_Montana.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap map;
    List<Position> routeCoordinates;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


 }
}
```

this error appears:

> No shuitable method found to override

[image]

does someone know what is happen ?
it's my first map in an app.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the type is wrong in your OnElementChanged method.

Try this:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
```

i.e. change View to Map

Comment: can be. I am trying it now